# Why does import of ctypes raise ImportError?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-2.6, importerror

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from struct import calcsize as _calcsize
ImportError: cannot import name calcsize

>>> from ctypes import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from struct import calcsize as _calcsize
ImportError: cannot import name calcsize
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you have another struct.py in your path somewhere.

Try this to see where python finds your struct module:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import struct
>>> inspect.getabsfile(struct)
'c:\\python26\\lib\\struct.py'
```

Comment: Schoolboy error. running cmd.exe was defaulting the CWD to the desktop. Where I had a temp script from a question I asked previously ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264833/python-class-factory-to-produce-simple-struct-like-classes ). I shall remember inspect though. Thank you.

Comment: Thou shalt not have two packages with the same name in thy package hierarchies. I was reckless enough to define a "struct" package, and got some interesting conflicts with NumPy. Should not really be a problem, one might think, but it is. Even with Python 3.