# Dynamically adding @property in python

Tags: python

I know that I can dynamically add an instance method to an object by doing something like:

```
import types
def my_method(self):
    # logic of method
# ...
# instance is some instance of some class
instance.my_method = types.MethodType(my_method, instance)
```

Later on I can call `instance.my_method()` and self will be bound correctly and everything works.

Now, my question: how to do the exact same thing to obtain the behavior that decorating the new method with @property would give?

I would guess something like:

```
instance.my_method = types.MethodType(my_method, instance)
instance.my_method = property(instance.my_method)
```

But, doing that `instance.my_method` returns a property object.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Although the title of the question _python: How to add property to a class dynamically?_ is basically the same, I don't believe that its accepted answer (including add-on to it) addresses the question generally.

Comment: @martineau - Nobody else seemed to believe that either, so the close vote has expired a long time ago.

Comment: @BoPersson: I stand corrected, technically the info in the [added-on answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1355444/355230) to that question does address the general question.

Comment: Is it important that other instances of this class do **not** have this property?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `property` descriptor objects needs to live in the **class**, *not* in the **instance**, to have the effect you desire.  If you don't want to alter the existing class in order to avoid altering the behavior of other instances, you'll need to make a "per-instance class", e.g.:

```
def addprop(inst, name, method):
  cls = type(inst)
  if not hasattr(cls, '__perinstance'):
    cls = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {})
    cls.__perinstance = True
    inst.__class__ = cls
  setattr(cls, name, property(method))
```

I'm marking these special "per-instance" classes with an attribute to avoid needlessly making multiple ones if you're doing several `addprop` calls on the same instance.

Note that, like for other uses of `property`, you need the class in play to be **new-style** (typically obtained by inheriting directly or indirectly from `object`), **not** the ancient legacy style (dropped in Python 3) that's assigned by default to a class without bases.

Comment: I just followed a link to this answer and found it very useful. However, perhaps due to changes in Python over the last few years, A few things didn't work out of the box for me. I had to change `cls.hasattr('__perinstance')` to `hasattr(cls, '__perinstance')`, and I had to add a line within the `if` block: `inst.__class__ = cls`. I hope this helps anyone else who sees this answer to get it working for them!

Comment: @Blckknght: I don't see how the original answer could have worked because it doesn't ever change the class of the instance to the newly created "per instance" one when that occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Since this question isn't asking about *only* adding to a spesific instance,
the following method can be used to add a property to the class, this will expose the properties to all instances of the class YMMV.

```
cls = type(my_instance)
cls.my_prop = property(lambda self: "hello world")
print(my_instance.my_prop)
# >>> hello world
```

*Note:* Adding another answer because I think @Alex Martelli, while correct, is achieving the desired result by creating a new class that holds the property, this answer is intended to be more direct/straightforward without abstracting whats going on into its own method.

Comment: -1, this does not just affect the behaviour of `my_instance`, it also sets `my_prop` for all other instances of class `type(my_instance)`

Comment: @ali_m, Right, thats the purpose, its adding the attribute to the class, The answer above (which is checked as being the correct one). is also adding the property to the class (not the instance).

Comment: No, what happens is that `cls = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {})` creates a new 'per-instance' class whose base is the type of the instance that we're adding the attribute to. When you then assign `inst.__class__ = cls` as in Blckknght's comment, this results in the attribute only being applied to `inst`, not to all instances of class `type(inst)`.

Comment: The answer isn't assigning the `__class__` (that was suggested in a comment). Whatever the case, the OP isn't explicitly asking how to change add a property to a **specific class instance**, if that were the case... my answer would be incorrect.