# Monkey Patching an attribute within a class?

Tags: python

Is it possible to Monkey Patch an attribute within a Python class? A quick google for "monkey patching python" returns a ton of results about patching `methods`, but no mention of changing fields within a class.

Patching Methods:

- [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object)
- [Duck punching a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415679/duck-punching-in-a-property-in-python)
- [changing methods and attributes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962962/python-changing-methods-and-attributes-at-runtime)

However, like I said, no mention of changing Class attributes/fields.

To give a somewhat contrived example, let's say I have a class which has a `multiprocessing` `queue`, and I want to patch it with a `threading Queue.Queue`.

```
import threading 
import multiprocessing

class MyClassWithAQueue(object):
        def__init__(self):
                self.q = multiprocessing.Queue()
```

Is there a way to patch this? Attempting to simply assign it via the class name before construction appears to do nothing.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyClassWithAQueue.q = Queue.Queue()
        myclass = MyClassWithAQueue()

        print myclass.q 
            # still shows as a multiprocessing queue
        >>><multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x10064493>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You must either create instance of the original class and then rewrite the actual value of the field, or monkey patch the class by replacing the constructor. But I don’t recommend using monkey patching at all. There are often much better ways to solve the problem you have.

Comment: What do you need to monkey patch in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the *order* in which the code runs.

`__init__` runs on instantiation, and is setting `self.q`, regardless of what if anything it was before. You can do one of the following:

---

Change it to a class attribute:

```
class MyClassWithAQueue(object):
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

MyClassWithAQueue.q = Queue.Queue()
myclass = MyClassWithAQueue()
print myclass.q
```

---

Or change the instance attribute:

```
class MyClassWithAQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = multiprocessing.Queue()

myclass = MyClassWithAQueue()
myclass.q = Queue.Queue()
print myclass.q
```