# Python: Copy properties with it's functions (fget, fset, fdel) from one class to another

Tags: python, function, properties, copy, setter

I know the questions about: ***copy properties***, or ***dynamic creation of properties*** has already been posted and also been answered ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677915/how-can-i-copy-a-python-class-property), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681272/can-i-get-a-reference-to-a-python-property) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-python-class-dynamically)). You could also find an excellent description, ***how the property function works*** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work?answertab=votes#tab-top).

But I think, that my question is a bit more specific. I do not only want to copy the property from one class to another. No, I also want the specific getter, setter and deleter functions to be copied to the destination class. After a whole day of searching for an answer, I decided to create an new post for this question.

So let me get a bit more in detail. A have an attribute class which is more a class group and stores property-classes:

```
class AttrContainer():  
    class a():
        ATTR=1
        @property
        def a(self):
            return self.ATTR

        @a.setter
        def a(self, n):
            self.ATTR = n + 3.021

    class b():
        ATTR=None
        @property
        def b(self):
            return "Something"

    class c():
        ATTR=None
        @property
        def c(self):
            return 3

        @c.setter
        def c(self, n):
            self.ATTR = n - 8.5201
```

As you can see, I have different getter, setter (not in the example: deleter) definitions of each property.

I want to use those properties with my item "wrapper" objects. But not all of item objects needs all properties, thats why I want to copy them dynamically into my wrapper classes.

So, this is how my item "wrapper" classes looks like:

```
class Item01Object():
    properties = ["a","c"]
    ATTR = None
    #[...]

class Item02Object():
    properties = ["b","c"]
    ATTR = None
    #[...]

#[...]
```

Because I can't set the properties dynamically while the item class will be instanced, I have to set them before I instance the class:

```
def SetProperties( ItemObject ):
    for propName, cls in AttrContainer.__dict__.iteritems():
        if propName in ItemObject.properties:
            prop = cls.__dict__[propName]
            fget = prop.fget if prop.fget else None
            fset = prop.fset if prop.fset else None
            fdel = prop.fdel if prop.fdel else None
            ItemObject.__dict__[propName] = property(fget,fset,fdel)
    return ItemObject()
```

In the end, i would instance my ItemObjects like this:

> `item = SetProperties(Item01Object)`

I would expect, that this will work...

```
>>> print item
<__builtin__.Item01Object instance at 0x0000000003270F88>
>>> print item.a
None
```

This is result is right, because I do not update my property ATTR.. 
Lets change the property:

```
>>> item.a = 20
>>> print item.a 
20
```

But this result is wrong, it should be `23.021` and **NOT** `20` . It looks like my properties do not using the setter functions from its classes.

Why? What do I wrong in my code?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to remove the inherited `object` of the ItemObject classes.. Now the code works.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually work *at all* because you cannot assign to `ItemObject.__dict__` if `ItemObject` is really a class. What are you *really* passing in? The exception I see is `TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: I edited my code. now it works. Sorry, I forgot to remove the `object` class in the `ItemXXObject` class definitions.

Comment: in Python 2 using `object` is **required** if you want setters and deleters to work.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't saw it in the documentation: `class property([fget[, fset[, fdel[, doc]]]])`
**Return a property attribute for new-style classes (classes that derive from object).** [Python Docs 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For properties *with setters and deleters* to work properly, your classes need to inherit from `object`: [Why does @foo.setter in Python not work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598077/why-does-foo-setter-in-python-not-work-for-me)

You can just copy the property object *itself* over to the new class. It'll hold references to the getter, setter and deleter functions and there is no need to copy those across.

For new-style classes, your code is not working; you cannot *assign* to a class `__dict__` attribute:

```
>>> item = SetProperties(Item01Object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in SetProperties
TypeError: 'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

Use `setattr()` instead to set attributes on new-style classes:

```
def SetProperties( ItemObject ):
    for propName, cls in AttrContainer.__dict__.iteritems():
        if propName in ItemObject.properties:
            setattr(ItemObject, propName, cls.__dict__[propName])
    return ItemObject()
```

Note that the `property` object is copied across wholesale.

Demo:

```
>>> class Item01Object(object):
...     properties = ["a","c"]
...     ATTR = None
...
>>> def SetProperties( ItemObject ):
...     for propName, cls in AttrContainer.__dict__.iteritems():
...         if propName in ItemObject.properties:
...             setattr(ItemObject, propName, cls.__dict__[propName])
...     return ItemObject()
... 
>>> item = SetProperties(Item01Object)
>>> item
<__main__.Item01Object object at 0x108205850>
>>> item.a
>>> item.a = 20
>>> item.a
23.021
```

You only have to copy across `property` objects to the target class *once* though; that your function returns an instance implies you are planning to use it for all instances created.

I'd make it a decorator instead:

```
def set_properties(cls):
    for name, propcls in vars(AttrContainer).iteritems():
        if name in cls.properties:
            setattr(cls, name, vars(propcls)[name])
    return cls
```

then use this on each of your `Item*Object` classes:

```
@set_properties
class Item01Object(object):
    properties = ["a","c"]
    ATTR = None

@set_properties
class Item02Object(object):
    properties = ["b","c"]
    ATTR = None
```

Demo:

```
>>> def set_properties(cls):
...     for name, propcls in vars(AttrContainer).iteritems():
...         if name in cls.properties:
...             setattr(cls, name, vars(propcls)[name])
...     return cls
... 
>>> @set_properties
... class Item01Object(object):
...     properties = ["a","c"]
...     ATTR = None
... 
>>> @set_properties
... class Item02Object(object):
...     properties = ["b","c"]
...     ATTR = None
... 
>>> item01 = Item01Object()
>>> item01.c = 20
>>> item01.c
3
>>> item02 = Item02Object()
>>> item02.b = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> item02.b
'Something'
```

Comment: Nice, that works fine. Thank you!! but How and why is `object` influencing the property? Your definitions: `class Item01Object(object):#[...]` , My definition:  `class Item01Object():#[...]`.

Comment: @MagSec: old-style classes simply do not have the plumbing to support full-on descriptors.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to get a static variable from my class (which is overwritten) and use this as the base of a new class to replace the existing? the question therefore is here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413046/python-how-to-rebase-or-dynamically-replace-a-class-with-a-different-base-class)