# scipy 0.11.0 to 0.12.0 changes a linear scipy.interpolate.interp1d, breaks my constantly updated interpolator

Tags: python, scipy, ode, interpolation

I have been playing around with a package that uses a linear scipy.interpolate.interp1d to create a history function for the ode solver in scipy, described [here.](http://zulko.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/delay-differential-equations-easy-with-python/)

The relevant bit of code goes something like

```
def update(self, ti, Y):
        """ Add one new (ti, yi) to the interpolator """
        self.itpr.x = np.hstack([self.itpr.x,  [ti]])
        yi = np.array([Y]).T
        self.itpr.y = np.hstack([self.itpr.y,  yi])
        #self.itpr._y = np.hstack([self.itpr.y,  yi])
        self.itpr.fill_value = Y
```

Where "self.itpr" is initialized in __init__:

```
def __init__(self, g, tc=0):
    """ g(t) = expression of Y(t) for t<tc """

    self.g = g
    self.tc = tc
    # We must fill the interpolator with 2 points minimum
    self.itpr = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(
        np.array([tc-1, tc]),  # X
        np.array([self.g(tc), self.g(tc)]).T,  # Y
        kind='linear',  bounds_error=False, 
        fill_value = self.g(tc))
```

Where `g` is some function that returns an array of values that are solutions to a set of differential equations and `tc` is the current time.

This seems nice to me because a new interpolator object doesn't have to be re-created every time I want to update the ranges of values (which happens at each explicit time step during a simulation).  This method of updating the interpolator works well under scipy v 0.11.0.  However, after updating to v 0.12.0 I ran into issues.  I see that the new interpolator now includes an array `_y` that seems to just be another copy of the original.  Is it safe and/or sane to just update `_y` as outlined above as well?  **Is there a simpler, more pythonic way to address this that would hopefully be more robust to future updates in scipy?**  Again, in v 0.11 everything works well and expected results are produced, and in v 0.12 I get an `IndexError` [when `_y` is referenced](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L409) as it isn't updated in my function while y itself is.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `_y` is just a copy of `y` that has been reshaped by `interp1d._reshape_yi()`. It should therefore be safe to just update it using:

```
  self.itpr._y = self.itpr._reshape_yi(self.itpr.y)
```

In fact, as far as I can tell it's only `_y` that gets used internally by the interpolator, so I think you could get away without actually updating `y` at all.

A much more elegant solution would be to make `_y` a property of the interpolator that returns a suitably reshaped copy of `y`. It's possible to achieve this by monkey-patching your specific instance of `interp1d` after it has been created (see Alex Martelli's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python) for more explanation):

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
itpr = interp1d(x,y)

# method to get self._y from self.y
def get_y(self):
    return self._reshape_yi(self.y)
meth = property(get_y,doc='reshaped version of self.y')

# make this a method of this interp1d instance only
basecls = type(itpr)
cls = type(basecls.__name__, (basecls,), {})
setattr(cls, '_y', meth)
itpr.__class__ = cls

# itpr._y is just a reshaped version of itpr.y
print itpr.y.shape,itpr._y.shape
>>> (100,) (100, 1)
```

Now `itpr._y` gets updated when you update `itpr.y`

```
itpr.x = np.arange(110)
itpr.y = np.random.randn(110)
print itpr._y.shape
>>> (110,) (110, 1)
```

This is all quite fiddly and not very Pythonic - it's much easier to fix the scipy source code (scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py). All you'd need to do is remove the last line from `interp1d.__init__()` where it sets:

```
self._y = y
```

and add these lines:

```
@property
def _y(self):
    return self._reshape_yi(self.y)
```