# How to dynamically generate methods and properties with Python?

Tags: python, object, properties, dynamically-generated, names

How to dynamically generate methods and properties in Python?

Let's assume that we have a long list and some class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
list = ["sky","sand","sea",...]
class SomeStaticObjClass( object ):    
    def __init__( self, arg, ):    
        # some code
```

...and want to dynamicaly add names and values to keep the funtionality with code example as follows :

```
sky = "sky"                                     # generate key and value
sky_OBJECT = SomeStaticObjClass( sky )          # generate name
def sky_Function( arg ): return arg.__class__   # generate function name
print sky_Function( sky_OBJECT )                # proceeding generated object name as argument
```

...then continue with other list members again...
Any help, please?

Comment: You are generating methods, not properties. What exactly did you want to happen?

Comment: ...I edited and added "methods", thanks. I want to generate (virtually) part of the code which is showed in lower frame from names list as in upper frame.

Comment: Did you want those methods to be added to *instances*, or to the *class*? There are duplicates for both approaches, and you cannot add properties to instances only.

Comment: To instances, please. Thanks for asking.

Comment: For methods, that's [Adding a Method to an Existing Object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/972)

Comment: For properties, that's [Dynamically adding @property in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2954331)

Comment: ...and for the classes?

Comment: For classes, just add them as attributes (using `setattr()` if you need to do it dynamically); wrap the function in a `property()` call first if they need to be a property. The [dupe for properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2954331) does just that.