# Why are Python descriptor methods not invoked when called with obj.x syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptor

I have a descriptor class `X` here. I try to use the descriptor `X` in another class `Y`

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        print('#### X.__get__ ####')
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('#### X.__set__ ####')
        self.value = value

class Y:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = X(10)

y = Y()
print(y.x)
y.x = 20
```

I was hoping that the statement `print(y.x)` would invoke `x.__get__` and the statement `y.x = 20` would invoke `x.__set__`, but it doesn't happen. When I run the above program, I just get this output.

```
<__main__.X object at 0x7fc65f947950>
```

Why were the descriptor methods not invoked?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think with `__getattr__`, `y.x` would invoke `x.__getattr__`. Instead, `y.x` would invoke `y.__getattr__`. However, I am trying to invoke `x.__getattr__` with `y.x` which is what descriptors are supposed to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding @property in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

To get the descriptor protocol methods invoked, you need to put the descriptor instance (`X()` in your case) on the `Y` **class**, not on the instance. This is described in some detail in the [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors) by Raymond Hettinger:

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`.

Note how `b.x` is transformed into the invocation of the descriptor obtained by dict access of **`type(b)`**. The `Y` class should look like this:

```
class Y:
    x = X(10)
```

However, since a single instance of `X` will be shared by all instances of `Y`, the `X` descriptor class will need to be modified to get and set the values from `instance` rather than from `self`.

Comment: In other words, `Y` needs to look like this: `class Y: \n x = X(10)`

Comment: @Asad modifications to `X` are also required, or all `Y` instances will share the same `x`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe They will share the same `X` instance, but I assume you could make it return some attribute of `instance` instead of `self`, so that the value returned would be unique to the `Y` instance.

Comment: @Asad yes, that is the modification required

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point, I've updated the answer to point out the pitfall.