# Adding a property to an existing object instance

Tags: python

I want to create a object with certain properties. I want to add them dynamically. Similar to [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance), but then with properties instead of methods. A simple example follows.

I like to create dynamically:

```
class A():
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, x):
        self._a = 10*x

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b
    @b.setter
    def b(self, x):
        self._b = 10*x
```

To do this with methods, i would do:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(70,80):
            self.__dict__[chr(i)] = types.MethodType(lambda self,x: x*i, self)
```

For properties I tried:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(70,80):
            def tmp(self, x):
                self._x = i*x
            self.__dict__[chr(i)] = property(fget=lambda self: self._i, fset=tmp)
```

I also found the `types.DynamicClassAttribute`, but I am not sure if this will help.

A relevant question is asked here, about adding properties to a class (in python 2): 
[Dynamically adding @property in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python) . I do not see how I can extend this to instances of a class.

### Background

I want to write a "driver" for the [lantz](https://github.com/LabPy/lantz/) project to use a camera via the [PyPylon](https://github.com/mabl/PyPylon) wrapper. The camera has some properties, which are not known in advance. I want to add all properties as Feats (some decorator supplied by lantz, which looks similar to a property: it has a getter and a setter).

Edit: it look likes [How to add property to a class dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically/) is the same question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work might be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically adding @property in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954331/dynamically-adding-property-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically/1355444#comment77890569_1355444) gave a hint to the answer.

The follow function (inspired on [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically/1355444#comment77890569_1355444)) adds a property to a single instance of a class. It does it by creating a new class on the fly.

```
def attach_dyn_propr(instance, prop_name, propr):
    """Attach property proper to instance with name prop_name.

    Reference: 
      * https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355444/509706
      * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448074
    """
    class_name = instance.__class__.__name__ + 'Child'
    child_class = type(class_name, (instance.__class__,), {prop_name: propr})

    instance.__class__ = child_class
```

Example and test:

```
def getter(self): print('Get!')
def setter(self, value): print('Set to {!r}!'.format(value))
def deleter(self): print('Delete!')
prop = property(getter, fset=setter, fdel=deleter)

class Foo: pass
foo = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()
attach_dyn_propr(foo, 'p', prop)

foo.p
foo2.p

... Get
... AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'p'
```