# How do I assign a property to an instance in Python?

Tags: python, attributes, properties, instance, variable-assignment

Using python, one can set an attribute of a instance via either of the two methods below:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    pass

>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.x = 1
>>> a.x
1
>>> setattr(a, 'b', 2)
>>> a.b
2
```

One can also assign properties via the property decorator.

```
>>> class Bar(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return 0


>>> a = Bar()
>>> a.x
0
```

My question is, how can I assign a property to an instance?

My intuition was to try something like this...

```
>>> class Doo(object):
    pass

>>> a = Doo()
>>> def k():
    return 0

>>> a.m = property(k)
>>> a.m
<property object at 0x0380F540>
```

... but, I get this weird property object. Similar experimentation yielded similar results. My guess is that properties are more closely related to classes than instances in some respect, but I don't know the inner workings well enough to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to dynamically add properties to a class after it's already created:

```
class Bar(object):
    def x(self):
        return 0

setattr(Bar, 'x', property(Bar.x))

print Bar.x
# <property object at 0x04D37270>
print Bar().x
# 0
```

However, you can't set a property on an instance, only on a class. You can use an instance to do it:

```
class Bar(object):
    def x(self):
        return 0

bar = Bar()

setattr(bar.__class__, 'x', property(bar.__class__.x))

print Bar.x
# <property object at 0x04D306F0>
print bar.x
# 0
```

See [How to add property to a class dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/python-how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically) for more information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they need this to be per-instance.  What you propose would affect all instances.

Comment: Argh! 1 minute before me!! :) +1

Comment: @Ross - I know, it says that in the answer. It simply isn't possible to add a property to an instance. See the thread I linked.

Answer (score 5):

Properties use [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=descriptor#descriptors) which only work on classes and thus
for all instances.  But you could use a combination of a descriptor on
a class that would consult a per-instance function.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         if 'x' in self.__dict__:
...             return self.__dict__['x'](self)
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> def k(self):
...     return 0
... 
>>> a.__dict__['x'] = k
>>> a.x
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the property directly to the class object:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
    pass    
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.__class__
__main__.Foo    
>>> setattr(a.__class__, 'm', property(lambda self: 0))
>>> a.m
0 
>>> a.m = 24
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we have taken @agf's solution and used a `lambda` function to define the class property.

```
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
a.__class__.f = property(lambda self: 57)
a.f  # 57
```

The following post provides more context: https://crosscompute.com/n/jAbsB6OIm6oCCJX9PBIbY5FECFKCClyV/_/Assign%20a%20class%20property%20to%20an%20instance