# Python official name for an attribute that is not a method

Tags: python, naming

According to my understanding the data members of objects in Python are referred to as 'attributes'.
Attributes that are callable are referred to as an object's 'methods', but I couldn't find a name for non-callable attributes, such as `val` in the following example:

```
class C:

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 42. # How would this be called?

    def self.action():
        """A method."""
        print(self.val)
```

I am sure different people may call `val` different things like 'field' or 'variable' but I am interested in an official name.

Comment: Why do you need an official name?

Comment: if I want to talk to others about, search for or otherwise reference certain constructs in a programming language I try to be as precise as possible.
I believe the best way to do that is to use terms that are official

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly hard to find official information on this topic. After reading [this](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) article I do believe it should simply be called `Class Variable` and `Instance Variable`.

---

### Attributes, Properties, Methods and Variables

`Attribute` is the *collection name* for the three names `Property`, `Method` and `Variable`. The latter two are prefixed by either `Class` or `Instance`. A `property` can only belong to the `Class`.

[image]

```py
class Foo:
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

    @property
    def c(self):
        return 3

    @classmethod
    def d(cls):
        return 4

    def e(self):
        return 5

Foo.a    # Class Attribute:      Class Variable
Foo().a  # Class Attribute:      Class Variable

Foo().b  # Instance Attribute:   Instance Variable

Foo.c    # Class Attribute:      Property

Foo.d    # Class Attribute:      Class Method
Foo().d  # Class Attribute:      Class Method

Foo.e    # Class Attribute:      Class Method
Foo().e  # Instance Attribute:   Instance Method
```

Sources

- [Difference between Class and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)
- [How do I assign a property to an instance in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117892/how-do-i-assign-a-property-to-an-instance-in-python)
- [What's the difference between a Python "property" and "attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374748/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-property-and-attribute)
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Diagram made in [Creately](https://app.creately.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if one exists, but I'd suggest just "instance attribute".

Features about this naming:

1. It excludes methods. Methods are all callable *class* attributes, so this wording excludes all methods.
2. It includes callable instance attributes. Consider the following code:

```py
class Container:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

c = Container(x)
c.item  # is an "instance attribute"
c.item == x  # True
```

Note that `c.item` is an "instance attribute" *regardless* of whether or not it's callable. I *think* this is behaviour you're after, but I'm not sure.

3. It excludes non-callable class attributes, e.g.

```py
class SomeClass:
    x = 5  # Is not an "instance attribute"
```

4. It includes per-instance attributes, e.g.

```py
obj.x = 5
obj.x  # Is an "instance attribute"
```

In the end, all of these features may be positives or negatives depending on *specifically* what you want. But I don't know specifically what you want, and this is as close as I can get. If you can provide more information, I can give a better suggestion.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea as `Attribute` is the collection name. Quote from the docs: [_'By the way, I use the word attribute for any name following a dot...'_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)