# Add an attribute to a class dynamically at runtime in Python

Tags: python

When I do the following:

```
def Welcome(email, temporaryPassword):
    model = object()
    model.TemporaryPassword = temporaryPassword
    model.Email = email
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'TemporaryPassword'
```

How do I dynamically create an object like I am doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: How to add property to a class dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/python-how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lambda object : ( http://codepad.org/ITFhNrGi )

```
def Welcome(email, temporaryPassword):
    model = type('lamdbaobject', (object,), {})()
    model.TemporaryPassword = temporaryPassword
    model.Email = email
    return model


t = Welcome('a@b.com','1234')
print(str(t.TemporaryPassword))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define a dummy class first:

```
class MyObject(object):
    pass

obj = MyObject()
obj.TemporaryPassword = temporaryPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only use the object as a data structure (i.e. no methods) you can use a `namedtuple` from the [`collections` package](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
def welcome(email, tmp_passwd):
    model = namedtuple('MyModel', ['email', 'temporary_password'])(email, tmp_passwd)
    ...
```

By the way, if your `welcome` function only creates the object and returns it, there is no need for it. Just:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Welcome = namedtuple('Welcome', ['email', 'temporary_password'])

ex = Welcome('me@example.com', 'foobar')
print ex.email
print ex.temporary_password
```