# Python class without attribute boilerplate

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming

Many of my classes look like the following class to represent accounts

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, age, id, balance):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.age = age
        self.id = id
        self.balance = balance

    def _info(self):
        return self.first, self.last, self.age, self.id, self.balance

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._info == other._info()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((type(self), self.info()))

    def ... # other methods follow
```

But really the only relevant information is the list of attributes I care about `first, last, age, id, balance`.  Is there a standard method to define Python classes that follow this structure?

At first glance I thought of `namedtuple` but I'm not sure that that allows me to add additional methods after the fact.  Really, I want something like the following

```
class Account(object):
    attributes = "first last age id balance"

    def ... # other methods
```

What is the best way of obtaining this?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how idiomatic it is, but the following satisfies your requirements:

```
class Slottable:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for slot, arg in zip(self.slots.split(' '), args):
            setattr(self, slot, arg)

    def _info(self):
        return tuple(getattr(self, attr) for attr in self.slots.split())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._info() == other._info()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((type(self), self._info()))


class Account(Slottable):
    slots = "first last age id balance"

    def fullname(self):
        return self.first + " " + self.last

matt = Account("Matthew", "Smith", 28, 666, 1E6)
john = Account("John", "Jones", 46, 667, 1E7)

d = {matt: 5, john: 6}  # Hashable

print matt.fullname()
#=> "Matthew Smith"
print john.fullname()
#=> "John Jones"
print matt == matt, matt == john
#=> True False
matt.age = 29  # Happy birthday!
print matt.age
#=> 29
```

Comment: Hrm, this doesn't handle mutation well.  In particular it doesn't follow the Single Point of Truth principle.  Redundant data is held both in `__info` and in each of the attributes.

Comment: @MRocklin Mutation?  Why would you want that?!?  :-)  I edited the example to handle mutation and keep the info only in the attributes dict.

Answer (score 1):

[Here are some recipes you can try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/python-how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically): override `__setattr__`, `__dict__`, `__slots__` and/or `init`.  Let us know what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Many libraries out there exist to cover this need: `attrs`, `dataclasses`, `pydantic`, ... and my new addition to this landscape, [`pyfields`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/).

Choice will mainly depend on the features you need or do not need. `pyfields` focuses on fields definition and optional validation and conversion, without *any* constraint on your class. Fields that *can* be native become as fast as python native attributes can be, while fields requiring callbacks (validators/converters) are implemented using descriptors.

You can blend your own constructor with the

```
from pyfields import field, init_fields

class Account(object):
    first = field(doc="first name")
    last = field(doc="last name")
    age = field(doc="the age in years")
    id = field(doc="an identifier")
    balance = field(doc="current balance in euros")

    @init_fields
    def __init__(self, msg):
        print(msg)

a = Account("hello, world!", first="s", last="marie", age=135, id=0, balance=-200000)
print(vars(a))
```

yields

```
hello, world!
{'balance': -200000, 'id': 0, 'age': 135, 'last': 'marie', 'first': 's'}
```

As opposed to other, more "all in one" libraries, `pyfields` concentrates on the fields and the constructor only, with a "minimum viable product" spirit. So if you would also like dict representation and conversion, hash, equality and comparison, you should add them on top of your class using another library. I am currently developing a [`mixture`](https://smarie.github.io/python-mixture/) lib providing mix-in classes for this, with the same philosophy of *a la carte* features - that you will be able to use with or without `pyfields`.

See [`pyfields` documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/) for details. Do not hesitate to provide feedback !