# Python - hardware handling, how to efficiently implement hardware registers as a property in an object

Tags: python, properties, hardware

I'm writing a code, which handles some hardware accessible via certain communication interface.
I'd like to define certain sets of registers as properties of the object describing the whole device.
Lets assume, that I have functions `hw_read(address, size)` and `hw_write(address, size, array_of_values)`, which allow to access the hardware.

Let's assume, that I have a block of registers with length 2, starting from address 10, and want to assign it to a property "reg1".
I can do it in a following way:

```
class my_hardware(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # Perform initialization
    return
  @property
  def reg1(self):
      return hw_read(10,2)
  @reg1.setter
  def reg1(self,value):
      hw_write(10,2,value)
```

The above implementation is not very convenient, as I have to provide address and size twice. It is error prone, especially if I have to define bigger number of registers.
Is it possible to implement it in such a way, that I could easily define
set a few registers like below:

```
dev1=my_hardware()
dev1.define_register("reg1",10,2)
dev1.define_register("reg2",12,6)
```

And then access them via:

```
dev1.reg1=(0x1234,0x3211)
print dev1.reg2
```

The second approach has also significant advantage, that list of registers (their names, addresses and sizes) may be read from an external text file (e.g. used also for VHDL
synthesis).

**Update - possible solution?**

After studying soe posts related to dynamical adding of properties, I have achieved the required functionality with the code shown below:

```
def hw_write (first,size,val):
    print "write:"+str(first)+", "+str(size)+" val="+str(val)

def hw_read (first,size):
    print "read:"+str(first)+", "+str(size)
    return (0x1234,)*size

class my_hardware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        return
    def add_reg(self,name,first,size):
        setattr(my_hardware,name,property(lambda self : hw_read(first,size), lambda self, x: hw_write(first,size,x)))
```

Below are sample results with dummy hw_read and hw_write functions:

```
>>> a=my_hardware()
>>> a.add_reg("reg1",10,2)
>>> a.add_reg("reg2",20,3)
>>> a.reg1
read:10, 2
(4660, 4660)
>>> a.reg2
read:20, 3
(4660, 4660, 4660)
>>> a.reg1=(10, 11)
write:10, 2 val=(10, 11)
>>> a.reg2=(10, 11, 12)
write:20, 3 val=(10, 11, 12)
```

I'll appreciate any suggestions whether the above solution is reasonable.

One problem (or feature?) which I can see, is that registers are defined "per class",
not "per instance". It may be helpful, if we have a few devices with the same register sets,
but may be misleading, if we want to use "my_hardware" class to access different devices with different register sets connected to the same bus.

**update 2**

I have found a solution, which allows to define derived classes describing particular devices, and define registers per class:

```
def hw_write (first,size,val):
    print "write:"+str(first)+", "+str(size)+"val="+str(val)

def hw_read (first,size):
    print "read:"+str(first)+", "+str(size)
    return (0x1234,)*size

class my_hardware(object):
    def __init__(self, base_address):
        self.ba = base_address
        return
    @classmethod
    def add_reg(myclass,name,first,size):
        setattr(myclass,name,property(lambda self : hw_read(self.ba+first,size), lambda self, x: hw_write(self.ba+first,size,x)))
```

Below is a sample session demonstrating correct operation:

```
>>> class dev1(my_hardware): 
...    pass
... 
>>> class dev2(my_hardware): 
...    pass 
... 
>>> dev1.add_reg("reg1",10,2)
>>> dev2.add_reg("reg2",15,3)
>>> a=dev1(100)
>>> b=dev2(200)
>>> a.reg1
read:110, 2
(4660, 4660)
>>> a.reg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dev1' object has no attribute 'reg2'
>>> b.reg1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dev2' object has no attribute 'reg1'
>>> b.reg2
read:215, 3
(4660, 4660, 4660)
```

As you can see, register reg1 is defined in devices of class "dev1", while register reg2 is defined in devices of class dev2. Of course in this case we also need a base address to be passed to each device, and therefore I had to add "base_address" to the constructor.

Thanks,
Wojtek

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-python-class-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update (Slight changes to match functionality of your second solution):* You could implement a small Domain-Specific Language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) using the Descriptor Protocol (https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/descriptor.html).  As an example, given a descriptor:

```
class RegisterDescriptor(object):
    """
    A descriptor that models reading and writing to hardware registers.
    """

    def __init__(self, offset, size):
        self.offset = offset
        self.size = size

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return hw_read(obj.base_address + self.offset, self.size)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if obj is None:
            raise AttributeError("Cannot set attribute")
        hw_write(obj.base_address + self.offset, self.size, value)
```

With this descriptor, you can now write a class and denote your registers semantically.  Again, for example:

```
class AddressableHardware(object):
    """
    Base class for addressable hardware components.

    Attributes:
    base_address -- the base address of the device.
    """

    def __init__(self, base_address):
        self.base_address = base_address

class MyHardware(AddressableHardware):
    """
    An example hardware device.
    """

    reg1 = RegisterDescriptor(2, 4)
    reg2 = RegisterDescriptor(6, 1)

    def __init__(self, base_address):
        AddressableHardware.__init__(self, base_address)

mh = MyHardware(0x2E)
print(mh.reg1)
mh.reg2 = b'\x00'
```

*Update*: This approach is different from your second solution as I've taken a more declarative approach, where each type of device would have its own class and associated methods (maybe some helper methods to hide low-level access to the device) and deal in more Pythonic datatypes.  Using the descriptor solution above, you would end up with something like:

```
class HardwareDeviceA(AddressableHardware):
    reg1 = RegisterDescriptor(10, 2)
    reg2 = RegisterDescriptor(20, 3)

    def __init__(self, base_address):
        AddressableHardware.__init__(self, base_address)

class HardwareDeviceB(AddressableHardware):
    reg1 = RegisterDescriptor(10, 4)

    def __init__(self, base_address):
        AddressableHardware.__init__(self, base_address)
```

This allows you to have multiple instances of device type A and B connected to the machine at different base addresses, and you don't need to setup their registers each time.

Comment: Brett, could you explain to me if your solution is equivalent to my, described in the second update, or maybe it is somehow better?
I do understand, that in your solution it is possible to generate field names dynamically, using setattr.

Comment: Oops, I copied in the wrong version of the solution to my interpreter.  Either way, I think the declarative approach is clearer as it gives you guarantees when you're writing your class about which registers will be available, and you should be putting device-related functionality as instance methods of the class.