# Splitting a list into new lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

So I have a list `plaintext`that contains `['A', 'A', 'R', 'O', 'N']` and I want to end up with a set of lists called `letter1`, `letter2`, `letter3`, and so on, that contain `['A']`, `['A']`, `['R']`, and so on. How do I go about doing this without cloning the list five times and removing the extra parts?

Comment: What have you already tried? SO won't write your code for you. If you've tried something, _edit your question_ to include your code. If not... well, go and try something! :P

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz SO might not, but somebody did :P

Comment: I know you won't write code for me, I just wanted to know if there was any function like this.

Comment: `[[e] for e in ['A', 'A', 'R', 'O', 'N']]`

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I want to know how to have each sublist that that code makes in `plaintext` and have them as a completely new list, that can be referenced with: `letter1 letter2` and so on.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, `plaintext` could be anything, of any length. I just had AARON as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list:

```
In [1]: letters = ['A', 'A', 'R', 'O', 'N']

#use list comprehension to iterate over the list and place each element into a list
In [2]: [[l] for l in letters]
Out[2]: [['A'], ['A'], ['R'], ['O'], ['N']]
```

To add titles, we typically use a dictionary. For example

```
#create a dictionary
letters_dict = {}

#iterate over original list as above except now saving to a dictionary
for i in range(len(letters)):
    letters_dict['letter'+str(i+1)] = [letters[i]]
```

This gives you the following:

```
In [4]: letters_dict
Out[4]:
{'letter1': ['A'],
 'letter2': ['A'],
 'letter3': ['R'],
 'letter4': ['O'],
 'letter5': ['N']}
```

You can now access each of the lists as follows:

```
In [5]: letters_dict['letters1']
Out[5]: ['A']
```

Finally, just for completeness, there's a cool extension of the dictionary method. Namely, using code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-python-class-dynamically), you can do the following:

```
#create a class
class atdict(dict):
    __getattr__= dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__= dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__= dict.__delitem__ 

#create an instance of the class using our dictionary:
l = atdict(letters_dict)
```

This way, you can do the following:

```
In [11]: l.letter1
Out[11]: ['A']

In [12]: l.letter5
Out[12]: ['N']
```

If you have no desire to store the values in an iterable or referencable object (ie dictionary, list, class) as you suggest in your question, then you could literally do the below:

```
letter1 = letters[0]
letter2 = letters[1]
letter3 = letters[2]
#and so forth ...
```

but as you can see, even with 6 variables the above becomes tedious.

Comment: Maybe something like this would work. Can i `letters1 = letters_dict['letters0']`?

Comment: You want `[[l] for l in letters]`, not `[list(l) for l in letters]`; the latter works as expected by coincidence (because length one strings are iterables that produce themselves), but for length != 1 strings, you'd end up with multielement lists by using `list`.

Comment: Ok then. If I happen to use something similar to this, I'll make sure to change that.

Comment: @ohyeah2389, I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, are you literally suggesting creating a new variable for each letter and assigning a list to that variable? I mean, by all means but that's most commonly impractical for subsequent tasks

Comment: I need to separate a list containing items which are single letters. I then need to scramble those letters in a way where they can later be read and unscrambled. And I'm a noob at python.

Comment: @ohyeah2389, could you edit your question by adding an example of the scrambling/unscrambling task you wish to have done?

Comment: No, because it's irrelevant, and if I need help with it, I can ask another question.

Comment: So what does the above code not do that you want it to do?

Comment: It works fine. Sorry for not clicking the checkmark.