# Defining a function in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to relatively Python and tkinter. I am trying the make a button for each item that I put in the list.

```
from tkinter import *

x = ['d', 'f']

class GUI:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        master.title("window")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Window")
        self.label.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.destroy)
        self.close_button.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

        for s in x:
            self.s_button = Button(master, text=s, command=self.s)
            self.s_button.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

    for a in x:
        def a(self):
            print (a)     

root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I run the code I receive a error `AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 's'`.

Comment: You can't create dynamic functions like that. I also don't see the need to do so.

Comment: You have `command=self.s` but you never assigned `self.s`

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the function you're defining in the loop, it's from `self.s`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create and access dynamic properties. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake: `command=self.s` looks for an attribute called "s". If you want to look for an attribute whose name is the content of the s variable, you should write `command=getattr(self, s)`.

Second mistake: `def a(self)` defines a class method called "a". If you want to programmatically generate named methods, you may do so **after** creating the class, with something like:

```
for a in x:
    def fun(self):
        print (a)
    setattr(GUI, a, fun)
```

Edit: this is still wrong, because the same variable `a`  is used for both functions.

Anyway, it looks quite strange to generate methods that way, I’d rather have a single method that takes the content to be printed as an argument, something like:

```
from tkinter import *

x = ['d', 'f']

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("window")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Window")
        self.label.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.destroy)
        self.close_button.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

        for s in x:
            self.s_button = Button(master, text=s, command=(lambda: self.print_(s)))
            self.s_button.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

    def print_(self, a):
        print (a)

root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Edit: this is still wrong because of the s variable that is shared since the for loop does not create a new scope. Only functions create new scopes. Here is some working code:

```
from tkinter import *

x = ['d', 'f']

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("window")

        self.label = Label(master, text="Window")
        self.label.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.destroy)
        self.close_button.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

        for s in x:
            self.s_button = Button(master, text=s, command=self.make_printer(s))
            self.s_button.grid(columnspan=5, sticky=W+E)

    def make_printer(self, a):
        def fun():
            print (a)
        return fun

root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Regardless of what button you push it prints f.

Comment: You’re right: I did the same mistake twice. There is no scope creation, so the same variable `s` is used for both commands. Will fix it.