# How to get the template source from Jinja2 Template object

Tags: python, jinja2

My program has a Jinja2 template loaded from a file.

`t = env.get_template(filename)`

Is it possible to get the template source (I mean the unrendered text, i.e. the contents of the file) from the `t` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#high-level-api), it does not seem that you can get the source directly. There are two things (at least) which can be done, however.

1. The `filename` property of `Template` is

   > The filename of the template on the file system if it was loaded from there. Otherwise this is None.

   So, if were indeed loaded from a file (and it still exists unmodified), you could get the contents by opening and read it.
2. You could attach it to the `Template` object yourself when loading it:

   ```
   def get_template_with_source(env, filename):
       t = env.get_template(filename)
       t.source = open(filename).read()
       return t
   ```

   For a nicer version, attaching a proper property dynamically, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically).