# Assigning attributes to class methods

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

Suppose I have a class that acts as a method container.  I have a config file that lists those methods in a dictionary.  In a program, I want to import the dictionary from config and iterate over it, calling methods from that class as I go.

The issue is that I need to have them be handled one way if the method is of one kind, and another way if another.  So the container class looks like:

```
class Circus(object):
    def clown(self):
        return print("*HONK*")

    def lion(self):
        return print("roar")

    def __call__(self):
        setattr(clown, 'isFunny', True)
        setattr(lion, 'isFunny', False)
```

My config file:

```
circus = {
    'funny_thing': Circus.clown,
    'unfunny_thing': Circus.lion
}
```

And the actual script:

```
for item in circus.items():
    if item[1].isFunny == True:
        item()
```

I've lost track of everything I've tried, but it's included separating this into two classes and creating an isFunny() method in each (returning true or false), assigning things to the class __dict__, placing `setattr()` in different places, using __init__, `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`.

What I expect is a simple `*HONK*`, but most everything spits out an `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isFunny'`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

For reference, a handful of the links I've tried:

- [Can I add attributes to class methods in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145317/can-i-add-attributes-to-class-methods-in-python)
- [Using setattr in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561174/using-setattr-in-python)
- [Instance, Class, and Static methods demystified](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/)
- [What are python attributes?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Python-function-attributes)
- [How to add a property to a class dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically)
- [What is the difference between init and call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call)

Comment: But why do you want to add those attributes to the methods? why not add them to the *objects* themselves and then all methods can access them

Comment: It has to do with the way I'm implementing this in real life, with the config file and everything.  The deadline is too close to rewrite everything right now, but I'm open to learning about best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__call__` is invoked when you *call* an instance. Given `c = Circus()`, `c()` is the same as `c.__call__()`. As a result, you are trying to check the attribute before it gets defined. Further, inside the `__call__` method, neither `clown` nor `lion` have been defined. They are both class attributes, and need to be used as such (i.e., either `Circus.clown` or `self.clown`). If you want to tag the methods, just do so directly in the `class` statement.

```
class Circus:
    def clown(self):
        print("*HONK*")

    def lion(self):
        print("roar")

    clown.isFunny = True
    lion.isFunny = False

circus = {
    'funny_thing': Circus.clown,
    'unfunny_thing': Circus.lion
}


for item in circus.items():
    if item[1].isFunny:
        item[1]()
```

However, note that `item[1]()` is still wrong, because the unbound method still expects an *instance* of `Circus` as its first argument. Some suggested fixes, depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish:

1. Make the methods class methods or static methods, so that no additional arguments are needed.
2. Store bound methods in the dict:

   ```
   c = Circus()
   circus = {
       'funny_thing': c.clown,
       'unfunny_thing': c.lion
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, it seems so obvious now!