# How do I define setter, getter for dynamically added attributes

Tags: python

I have a class as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add_attr(self, name):
        setattr(self, name, 'something')
```

How do I define custom setter, getter for `self.name`? I cannot use `__setattr__`, `__getattribute__` because that will change the behaviour of `add_attr` too.

EDIT: the users of this class will add arbitrary number of attributes with arbitrary names:

```
a = A()
a.add_attr('attr1')
a.add_attr('attr2')
```

I want custom behavior for only these user added attributes.

Comment: Hi @Priyatham, perhaps you could use a dictionary for setting/getting this attrs? check my answer below

Comment: What do you want the getters and setters do to? Normal attribute setting would work if nothing special needs to happen

Comment: @NChauhan It is some custom logic

Comment: How will the object learn about the custom getter & setter for each dynamically added attribute? Will the user pass them as functions to `add_attr`?

Answer (score 2):

Building off @Devesh Kumar Singh’s answer, I would implement it in some way like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrs = {}

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.attrs:
            self.set_attr(key, value)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
         if key in self.__dict__.get(attrs, {}):
             return self.__dict__['get_attr'](self, key)
         return object.__getattribute__(self, key)

    def get_attr(self, key):
        r = self.attrs[key]
        # logic
        return r

    def set_attr(self, key, value):
        # logic
        self.attrs[key] = value

    def add_attr(self, key, value=None):
        self.attrs[key] = value
```

`add_attr` is only used to initialise the variable the first time. You could also edit `__setattr__` to set all new attributes in the `self.attrs` rather than `self.__dict__`

Comment: Have you tried running this? I think this raises `RecursionError`. Because you are checking for membership in `self.attrs` which itself calls `__getattr__`

Answer (score 2):

Custom getter and setter logic? That's what a `property` is made for. Usually these are used to magically mask function calls and make them look like attribute access

```py
class MyDoubler(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return x * 2

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

>>> md = MyDoubler(10)
>>> md.x
20
>>> md.x = 20
>>> md.x
40
>>> md._x
20
```

But there's no rule saying you can't abuse that power to add custom behavior to your getters and setters.

```py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def default_getter_factory(name):
        def default_getter(self):
            return self.name
        return default_getter

    @staticmethod
    def default_setter_factory(name):
        def default_setter(self, value):
            setattr(self, name, value)
        return default_setter

    def add_attr(self, name, getterfactory=None, setterfactory=None):
        private_name = f"_{name}"

        if getterfactory is None:
            getterfactory = self.__class__.default_getter_factory
        if setterfactory is None:
            setterfactory = self.__class__.default_setter_factory

        getter, setter = getterfactory(private_name), setterfactory(private_name)

        getter = property(getter)
        setattr(self.__class__, name, getter)
        setattr(self.__class__, name, getter.setter(setter))
```

That said this is all a bit silly, and chances are that whatever it is you're trying to do is a thing that shouldn't be done. Dynamic programming is all well and good, but if I were to review code that did this, I would think very long and hard about alternative solutions before approving it. This reeks of technical debt to me.

Comment: No the user doesn't add their own getter, setter logic. It is just different from default behaviour but consistent across all attributes added. Can you please see my answer and tell me if it is/isn't good programming practice?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility I could think of is to have a dictionary of dynamic attributes, and set and get the dynamic attributes using the dictionary

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        #Dictionary of attributes
        self.attrs = {}

    #Set attribute
    def set_attr(self, name):
        self.attrs[name] = 'something'

    #Get attribute
    def get_attr(self, name):
        return self.attrs.get(name)

a = A()
a.set_attr('var')
print(a.get_attr('var'))
```

The output will be `something`

Or an alternate is to use `property` decorator to add arguments explicitly outside the class, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1355444/8591431)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = A()
#Add attributes via property decorator
a.attr_1 = property(lambda self: self.attr_1)
a.attr_2 = property(lambda self: self.attr_2)

#Assign them values and print them
a.attr_1 = 4
a.attr_2 = 6

print(a.attr_1, a.attr_2)
```

The output will be `4 6`

Comment: I would like a solution that works simply as `a.var` without using methods like `set_attr`, `get_attr`

Comment: You can use custom getters and setters on predefined attributes, and not on dynamic attributes, otherwise you can override property attribute outside the class for your dynamic attributes @Priyatham will that work?

Comment: Yes, that would work and I finally figured out how to get it to work.

Comment: Great @Priyatham Do you want me to add that bit to my answer? Also if my answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Comment: Yes, please add it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194417/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-priyatham).

Comment: Okay I added it to the answer @Priyatham please have a look and let me know if it works for you, and if you have any questions about it

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna answer my own question just for reference. This is based on others' answers here. The idea is to use default `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` on attributes not added through `add_attr`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attrs = {}

    def add_attr(self, name):
        self.attrs[name] = 'something'

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            object.__getattribute__(self, 'attrs')[name]  # valid only if added by user
            # custom logic and return 
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
           return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        # similar to __getattribute__
```

Comment: Hi @Priyatham, if my answer worked for you in coming up with this, could you consider marking my answer as accepted and/or upvote it?

Comment: Why not `if name in self.attrs: # custom logic; else: return type(self).__getattribute__(self, name)`