# Can I patch an arbitrary object instance to throw when used?

Tags: python

### Motivation

I have singleton objects I am replacing with new instances.  I want to be sure that nobody uses stale references to invalidated objects.  I have tried a few solutions (listed below) that haven't worked and now I'm wondering if this is a fools errand.

My desired user experience is something like

```
singleton = OriginalClass()
user_variable = singleton

...

make_radioactive(singleton) 
singleton = NewSingletonClass() 
# User code should also update here but what if they dont?

...

# If they didn't update correctly I want this to break
user_variable.do_something()
Exception: Object has been invalidated
```

### Requirements:

1. No added overhead to object before it is destroyed/deprecated
2. Any attribute access or method calls on the old instance throws an exception of my choosing
3. The new instance of singleton may be of the same or different type

### Approaches considered and rejected

**1: Override **getattribute** at runtime**

```
def make_radioactive(some_object):
    def throw(self, name):
        raise Exception("Using an invalidated instance")
    some_object.__getattribute__ = throw
```

I was hopeful about this but it does not work because of [special method lookup rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).  `__getattribute__` is accessed through the class not the instance and monkeypatching it on the class would invalidate all instances not just one of them.

**2: Erase `__dict__`**

```
def make_radioactive(some_object):
    some_object.__dict__ = {}
```

This is close to what I want but the exception users would see is

```
AttributeError: 'ClassType' object has no attribute 'attribute_name'
```

instead of

```
MyCustomExceptionType: You used an invalidated instance
```

And it only works on variables not methods

**3: Require common base class and override `__getattribute__`**

```
class Destroyable(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__radioactive = False
    def make_radioactive(self):
        self.__radioactive = True
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if object.__getattribute__(self, '_radioactive'):
            raise MyCustomException("Accessed an inavlidated object")
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

This gives me a custom exception message but requires inheriting from a base class and adds overhead to normal object operations before `make_radioactive` is called

Comment: Maybe you can define a `radioactive` [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), iterate over the target object's `__dict__`, and replace all values with this property?

Comment: Replace the invalid instance's `__dict__` with a dict subclass that throws your error in the appropriate methods?

Comment: @0x5453 sadly look like properties [have to be added to the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically) not an instance

Comment: @Hammer Wow, today I learned.

Comment: @jasonharper I just tried playing around with that for a while and I couldn't get it to work.  I guess I don't understand how attribute access and the `__dict__` member interact but it just keeps throwing attribute error before ever calling my custom `__getitem__`

Comment: @Hammer, ..one can change an instance's classes after it already exists. I once wrote production code for exactly that purpose; see https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/isg-state-machine-framework/blob/master/isg/state_machine/__init__.py, in particular the Retargetable class.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to change the `__class__` attribute of the object you want to invalidate. Change it to a custom class that raises an error in the `__getattribute__` method. In my tests similar to the one you describe, it throws the error as you expected when trying to access attributes or methods.

If the objects type has `__slots__`, then changing class to a trivial class will throw `TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'X' object layout differs from 'Y'`. To avoid that we can dynamically create an invalid subclass of the passed objects type.

```py
invalid_classes = {}
def make_radioactive(some_object):
    global invalid_classes
    c = type(some_object)

    if c not in invalid_classes:
        # To avoid "TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'X' object layout differs from 'Y'"
        # We create a subclass of the objects class
        class A(c):
            # override __getattribute__ to always throw an error
            def __getattribute__(self, name):
                raise MyCustomException("Accessed an inavlidated object")
        # Remember it so we don't need to recreate on every call with same type of object
        invalid_classes[c] = A

    # Assign new class to the object
    some_object.__class__ = invalid_classes[c]
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for!  I had no idea you could assign to `__class__`.  Thanks