# @property methods as first-class-functions

Tags: python, properties

I'd like to use @property-decorated functions as first-class functions, and I'm not sure it's possible.

As a toy example,

```py
class A:
    _x = 5
   
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

class B:
   _x = 12
   


a_instance = A()
b_instance = B()

# Here's the line that I have a question about
b_instance.x = bind_somehow(a_instance.x)

assert (b_instance.x == 12)
```

Obviously, if I just set `b_instance.x = a_instance.x` then `b_instance.x` is going to be `5`. Is there any way to `bind` the @property decorated function, or does referencing it at all always execute the getter?

Is this possible?

Comment: What does the last line: `assert (b_instance.x == 12)` mean? I can't understand why you want that.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. `a_instance.x` will call the method to get the property value, it doesn't return a reference to the method.

Comment: Don't use a property if you need to be able to treat it as a function.

Comment: @quamrana They're trying to copy a property dynamically from one class to another the way you could with a method.

Comment: I also don't think you can have properties that are attached to instances. Properties are implemented using descriptors in the class dictionary; if you assign it directly to an instance it won't be called.

Comment: @quamrana I'd like `b_instance.x` to execute the function `x` in the context of `b_instance`. IE, look up `self._x` and return the value.

Comment: Note that this is something I can do with functions. If `x` is not a property and has to be accessed as `x()`, I can do `b_instance.x = a_instance.x`, then execute `b_instance.x()` and get `12`. EDIT: No, I can't, I'm a fool. `self` would be bound to `a_instance`. I'd need to do `b_instance.x = partial(A.x(b_instance))`

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically) help at all?