# why 'object' class doesn't have user set attributes

Tags: python

Every class in python inherits from the class 'object.' I am wondering about the internal mechanism of the 'object' class implementation. Why cannot the 'object' class be assigned any user-attributes? I am convinced that it is related to memory-management but what if the user thinks of implementing the memory-management himself, why can't he override 'object' class in python? This is based on my interest and want to know about which might not have any programmatic application but would be nice to know the internal feature of the language itself.

Comment: Actually, under Python 2.x, only new-style classes inherit from ``object``. (Well, and in Python 3.x, but there all classes are new-style, so it's pointless to mention it).

Comment: That's not a great reason for a downvote -- but a great place for an answer to educate the asker... seems like a well thought out and valid question to me. +1

Comment: Jack, can you clarify whether you're talking about adding attributes to the object class or to instances of that class?

Comment: I am talking about adding attributes to the instances of object class.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for the wonderful answers really educating me. I really appreciate the answers and comment from all of you. This is really fruitful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to derive the reasoning from first principles, I might think about it in terms of the [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) mechanism.  Some kinds of classes only need a tiny number of attributes, and the set of attributes is always fixed for every instance, and so the flexibility of a "dict" like user attributes capability would be wasteful of cpu (looking up dynamically named attributes) and space (the overhead of an empty dict, small but non-zero), which can really add up to a lot of overhead if there are a large number of instances.

of course this is exactly the problem the `__slots__` mechanism solves.  space is allocated on the object for the attributes defined in slots.  if there's a `__dict__` attribute, non-slot attributes can be found there, and if there's no `__dict__` attribute, you get neither the dynamic attributes nor the cost of the unneeded dict object (which is an additional heap object other than the instance itself).

As for why `object` itself does not have a slot for `__dict__`, well, even if a subclass indicated that they didn't *need* the `__dict__` slot, if they inherit from a class that *does*, then the instance must still have a `__dict__`;  if `object` had a `__dict__` then absolutely every class would also pay the price of having a `__dict__`, even if they didn't need it.

Instead; subclasses get `__dict__` (and `__weakref__`, for analogous reasons) unless they themselves define a `__slots__` class attribute.

And why would you need a plain-ol instance of `object` at all?  Do you just need a bag of attributes?  well then use a `dict`.  If you actually need an object of some kind with behaviors and attributes, then you are making a subclass anyways.

About the only reason I can ever imagine using `object()` instead of a subclass of `object`, is when the only feature of the instance that is of interest is its identity.  This would come up when a function takes arguments, and for which `None` or some other obvious sentinel value should be understood as distinct from the default:

```
BAR_DEFAULT = object()
def foo(bar=BAR_DEFAULT):
    if bar is BAR_DEFAULT:
        #...
```

In which case you neither need nor particularly want attributes on the instance of `object`,

Answer (score 3):

Types defined in C can never have user-assigned attributes. If you want to replace `object` globally then you'll need to iterate over every single class in existence, then replace `__builtin__.object` to catch all future class creation. And even that isn't reliable since the old object could be bound somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed on StackOverflow, but I'm having trouble finding the discussion to link it.

The reason I wondered is because I wanted to simplify this example:

```
class Box(object):
    pass

box = Box()
box.a = "some value"
box.b = 42
```

Here I'm using `box` as a sort of dictionary, one where the keys can only be identifiers.  I do this because it's more convenient to write `box.a` than `box["a"]`.

I wanted to do this:

```
box = object()
box.a = "some value"  # doesn't work
```

The reason is that `object` is the root of all objects in Python.  Any attributes that `object` has must be in any derived type.  If you want to make a large list containing a large number of objects, you want them to be as small as possible so you don't run out of memory.  So `object` itself is minimal.

EDIT: I found the link I was trying to remember:

[struct objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878710/struct-objects-in-python)