# If the convention in Python is to capitalize classes, why then is list() not capitalized? Is it not a class?

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions

Often when I see class definitions `class Foo:`, I always see them start with upper case letters.

However, isn't a list `[]` or a dict `{}` or some other built-in type, a class as well? For that matter, everything typed into the Python's IDLE which is a keyword that is automatically color coded in purple (with the Window's binary distribution), is itself a class, right?

Such as `spam = list()`

`spam` is now an instance of a `list()`

So my question is, why does Python allow us to first of all do something like `list = list()` when nobody, probably, does that. But also, why is it not `list = List()`

Did the developers of the language decide not to use any sort of convention, while it is the case that most Python programmers do name their classes as such?

Comment: see pep8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python coding standards/best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356161/python-coding-standards-best-practices)

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I can see why you would think so based on my choice of title and the tags. The problem is that I was more confused why `list()` is then not capitalized. That is where the target of the question was intended.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, uppercase-initial classes are the convention, as outlined in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

You are correct that many builtin types do not follow this convention.  These are holdovers from earlier stages of Python when there was a much bigger difference between user-defined classes and builtin types.  However, it still seems that builtin or extension types written in C are more likely to have lowercase names (e.g., `numpy.array`, not `numpy.Array`).

Nonetheless, the convention is to use uppercase-initial for your own classes in Python code.

Answer (score 4):

All are in the end design decisions.

> > [...] why does python allow us to first of all do something like `list = list()`

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ says (try also `>>> import this`)

- Simple is better than complex.
- Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

And this would be a special case.

> > [...] why is it not `list = List()`

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names says:

> ###Class Names
>
> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
>
> The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where
> the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.
>
> ***Note that there is a separate convention for builtin names: most
> builtin names are single words (or two words run together), with the
> CapWords convention used only for exception names and builtin
> constants.*** [emphasis mine]

All other classes should use the CapWords convention. As `list`, `object`, etc are built-in names, they follow this *separate convention*.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the only person who *really* knows the entire answer to your question is the [BDFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_Dictator_for_Life). Convention outside of the types implemented in C is definitely to use upper-case (as detailed in PEP8). However, it's interesting to note that not *all* C-level types follow the convention (i.e. `Py_True`, `Py_False`) do not. Yes, they're constants at Python-level, but they're all `PyTypeObject`s. I'd be curious to know if that's the only distinction and, hence, the difference in convention.

Answer (score 2):

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the place to go for code style.

To address your question on why `list = list()` is valid, `list` is simply a name in the global namespace, and can be overriden like any other variable.

Comment: how about `datetime.date` class?

Comment: @Grienders basically anything can be overriden in Python, because everything is a name which can point to whatever you want it too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), a nice set of guidelines for Python developers:

> Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention.
>   Classes for internal use have a leading underscore in addition.

PEP 8 is directed at Python development for the standard library in the main Python distribution, but they're sensible guidelines to follow.