# creating class properties dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaprogramming

I am looking for a way to dynamically create classes with specific properties accessible via typical instance notation.

```py
       DynoOne = createClass('DynoOne',props=['A','B'])
       d = DynoOne (database='XYZ')
       d.A = d.B + 1

       DynoTwo = createClass('DynoTwo',props=['A','C','E'])
       q = DynoTwo (database='QRS')
       q.A = q.C + 2*q.E
```

Details of how the "props" are actually acquired and modified would be hidden.
This also makes it easier to add access to new props as they become available.

I have experimented with techniques such as the following, to get a feel for how python can dynamically produce basic class attributes:

[Class factory to produce simple struct-like classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264833/class-factory-to-produce-simple-struct-like-classes/1275088#1275088)

My initial reading on python suggests that class properties are one way to handle introducing getter/setter methods for access.

What's not clear is how to dynamically specify property names in the factory constructor method (whether using decorators or explicit property() call)

E.g., using property() . . .

```py
   class DynamicClass( someBase ):

       def dynamic_getter(self):
           # acquire "stuff"
           return stuff

       def dynamic_setter(self,stuff):
           # store  "stuff"
           pass 

       dynamic_property_name = property(fget=dynamic_getter,fset=dynamic_setter)
```

When the class is declared/constructed, I need to create a set per requested prop.  E.g., the DynoOne class would have separate property/setter/getter for 'A' and 'B'.

I suspect that a template-based eval() strategy would work, but I am likely missing some more fundamental and effective technique.

Enlightenment and learning opportunities are appreciated :-)

Comment: lets say that I have the following:

Comment: I have done some experiments with using type() in a factory context,
In particular, for establishing local, instance attributes using __init__.

In the case of interest however, the content requires computation

I understand that are ways to do this with a function interface
```python
   print ('computed content {}'.format(my_instance.getComputed() ))
```
But I would still like access to be of the form:
```python
   print ('computed content {}'.format(my_instance.Computed))
```

Comment: sorry about the formatting -- first time I have posted and learning to navigate the API . . .

Comment: Well, that's exactly what `property` is for, or you can implement your own custom descriptor object if `property` doesn't work for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three-argument for of `type` lets you create classes dynamically. So, a sketch:

```
def dynamic_getter(self):
    # acquire "stuff"
    return stuff

def dynamic_setter(self,stuff):
    # store  "stuff"
    pass 

DynamicClass =  type('DynamicClass', (SomeBase,), {"dynamic_property_name":property(fget=dynamic_getter,fset=dynamic_setter)})
```

Or, more concretely:

```
In [1]: class SomeBase:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self._foo = 42
   ...:
   ...: def dynamic_getter(self):
   ...:     # acquire "stuff"
   ...:     return self._foo
   ...:
   ...: def dynamic_setter(self,stuff):
   ...:     # store  "stuff"
   ...:     pass
   ...:
   ...: DynamicClass =  type('DynamicClass', (SomeBase,), {"dynamic_property_name":property(fget=dynamic_getter,fset=dynamic_setter)})

In [2]: instance = DynamicClass()

In [3]: instance.dynamic_property_name
Out[3]: 42
```

Note: `type` is literally a class object like any other, and calling it in it's three-argument form is a constructor for new class object instances, it is the class that creates other class objects, i.e. a metaclass. Indeed, you can think of a class definition statement as syntactic sugar for the above.

A template-based with `exec` (if you want to use a complex statement, you'd need `exec`, `eval` only allows expressions) approach is also viable, if you find that easier to work with. Indeed, that is how `collections.namedtuple` works in the standard library.

Note: you seem to be confused about the nature of properties in Python. Instance attribtus are not specified on the class, rather, you'd add a function that initializes those instance attributes (typically `__init__`) but you can add instance attributes *anywhere*, even outside of a method/class.

Comment: ah -- this looks promising -- now I see how to setup the property() relationship in the type() call !

Comment: is there a way to use something like  __slots__ to guard against unexpected attribute reference?    I.e., I want to guard against  thing like ```

my_instance.NOT_SUPPORTED_PROPERTY
```

Comment: @Tomie yeah, just use `__slots__`.

Comment: @Tomie although, Python will always throw an error if you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist. `__slots__` will guard against common typo bugs like `instance.som_var = 42` when you meant `instance.some_var = 42`

Comment: if I assign `__slots__` based on the prop names, I get `ValueError: 'A" in __slots__ conflicts with class variable` when `type()` is invoked

Comment: if I assign `__slots__` based on the created properties, I get `TypeError: __slots__ items must be strings, not 'property'`

Comment: @Tomie because you cannot have slots that have the same name as a property. Just don't add that, you won't need it. Slots are for *instance attribtues*, `property` objects are class-level attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199036/discussion-between-tomie-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 0):

In python, instance variables are stored under a dict which can be used to create dynamic instance variables at the time of object creation of a class.

Let's say, I have a dict {'a':1} in which the key 'a' should be assigned as a variable and 1 as its value.

Under`__init__` function, we can do like,

```
self.__dict__['a'] = 1
```

We can use a for loop to iterate over the dictionary and do the above to create dynamic variables.

As per @chepner suggestion, we can also use `setattr` function to set variables dynamically.

Comment: `setattr(self, 'a', 1)` would be better. Don't use the dunder names directly if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have edited the answer properly.